# How to change the value of a selected cell in a DynamicGridView through a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to change the value of the selected cell in the DataGridView (dgvDynamic) to be equal to the current data in the textbox (txtSelectedCellData).

```
dgvDynamic.SelectedCells = txtSelectedCellData.Text
```

However, this line becomes underlined in red stating: 
"Property of 'SelectedCells' is 'ReadOnly'"
"Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection'"

How else would you be able to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it I can use (DataGridViewName).CurrentCell.Value = (textboxname).text to show the value of the textbox into the DataGridView selected cell.

Here is the new line:

```
dgvDynamic.CurrentCell.Value = txtSelectedCellData.Text
```

Thanks.